# Laravel mix vue-template-compiler must be installed as a peer dependency

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, laravel-mix, vue-loader

i got a fresh laravel installation, everything compile well but when I install vuex or vue router through npm, compiling wont work anymore, i got this error:

> Error: [vue-loader] vue-template-compiler must be installed as a peer
>   dependency, or a compatible compiler implementation must be passed via
>   options.

Answer (score 25):

The **vue** and **vue-template-compiler** module version must be the same in your **package.json**.

This was my code:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-loader": "^15.5.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
},
```

I changed the **vue** version to 2.5.21, then ran **npm update** to update the base version of VueJS.

Comment: I had the same issue. vue-template-compiler 2.5.22 and vue 2.5.17. Updated vue to ^2.5.22 (same as vue-template-compiler) and it works.

Comment: Why Laravel does not add `vue-loader` and `vue-template-compiler` as dev dependencies when compiling assets with mix?

Comment: i have the same error,. it didn't worked. my version is 2.6.10

Answer (score 0):

`npm install vue-loader --save-dev`

`npm install vue-template-compiler --save-dev`

Comment: //Would have been really helpful if you posted your package.json but I hope this helps

Comment: It would be good to include a little explanation (e.g. "looks like you are missing some dependencies:") as well as formatting your commands by surrounding them with backticks (`).